# public Static Dictionary not retaining value

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a proxy WCF service that resides in IIS on the Client side and makes calls down into an external WCF services(which is called by the windows service). As the the stats are collected from the windows service they get stored in the following m_statList dictionary.

```
public static Dictionary<int, LinkedList<StatValue>> m_statList = new Dictionary<int,    LinkedList<StatValue>>();
public static Dictionary<int, LinkedList<StatValue>> Stats
{
    get
    {
        return m_statList;
    }
}
```

The m_statList retains the values as the service runs, but once the proxy makes the call in the m_statList has a count set to zero.

Heres how I make the call from the Internal Proxy Service:

```
public Dictionary<int, List<StatValue>> GetStats(DateTime getFromDate, List<int> getValueList)
    {
        Dictionary<int, List<StatValue>> returnList = new Dictionary<int, List<StatValue>>();

        foreach (var stat in DashboardCollectorService.Stats.Where(k => getValueList.Contains(k.Key)))
        {
            returnList.Add(stat.Key, stat.Value.Where(s => s.StatDateTime > getFromDate).ToList<StatValue>());
        }

        return returnList;
    }
```

Im not sure my m_statList is empty when I call stats from the Proxy.

```
public class DashboardProxyService : IDashboardWCFService
{
    DashboardWCFService buffer = new DashboardWCFService();

    Dictionary<int, List<StatValue>> IDashboardWCFService.GetStats(DateTime getFromDate, List<int> getValueList)
    {
        return buffer.GetStats(getFromDate, getValueList);
    }

    List<StatType> IDashboardWCFService.GetStatTypes()
    {
        return buffer.GetStatTypes();
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide some code that adds any values to the m_statList dictionary. Otherwise it is indeed empty. To debug this - add some logging when you call GetStats - just dump to the log everything you can - all keys from the dictionary, all parameters. May be key doesn't match, or source dictionary is empty... Debug the thing! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you disabled the IIS web garden for the application pool?

for IIS 6, see http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/659f2e2c-a58b-4770-833b-df96cabe569e.mspx?mfr=true

for IIS 7, Open the IIS control panel.  Click on the "Application Pools" node in the left-hand tree.  Locate the application pool for your application and right-click.  Select the menu option for "Advanced Settings...".  Under "Process Model" heading you should have the following settings:

```
Maximum Worker Processes = 1
Idle Time-out = 0
```

The first of these, "Maximum Worker Processes" controls the web garden, the later just keeps IIS from unloading your application when idle.

Answer (score 0):

Static data lives until `AppDomain` lives. IIS by default can restart application pool, and unload your `AppDomain`. So, next time you call IIS-hosted service, there will be another domain.

Comment: The stats are being collected in the windows service, which continually runs.

Comment: My proxy service is calling into that.